# Error while adding WCF service as connected service in .net core 2.0 web application

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am using VS 2017, when I try to add WCF service as a connected service in asp.net core web application using "Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider", it errors out, here are the error logs:

```
Importing web service metadata ...
Number of services found: 1
Restoring NuGet packages ...
Building solution ...
Scaffolding service reference code ...
Warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Channels.StandardBindingImporter
Error: The method or operation is not implemented.

Error:Error: No endpoints compatible with .Net Core apps were found.


Error:An unknown error occurred while invoking the service metadata component.
Failed to generate service reference.
```

Anybody, workaround for this issue?

I am able to add these WCF services in .net framework applications successfully.

Edit 1: Tested again with VS 15.5.1, still not working. So .Net Core does not fully support message security: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/1354
I have message security in WCF, so this makes sense why I am not able to add my WCF service as connected service in .Net core project.

Comment: Try to create a proxy server, which will forward the requests

Comment: Thanks. I went ahead and created a separate library project to get things moving.